# Full page zooming with typeface.js or cufon

Tags: javascript, html, cufon, mipmaps, typeface.js

Is there a way to "mipmap" with typeface.js or cufon, such that a full-page zoom in a browser will not destroy the crispness of the rendered text? I could not find much information about this.

For an example, on this page http://thatguynamedandy.com/blog/text-replacement-comparison zooming blurs Cufon and typeface.js, and sIFR doesn't zoom with the page at all (being a Flash solution).

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here is a description of mipmapping http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap. It is normally used to make textures blurrier for performance in 3-d games, but I want to do the reverse (have higher res loaded for zoom)

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you want, but could you get away with straight [@font-face](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/)?  It's supported really well, now, and can be [set up with online tools in minutes](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).  Then the client has true fonts, no scaling, and it's selectable.

Comment: Cool.  If that works, I'll make it an "answer", and you can mark this as closed.